# Oracle sql issue with returning rows that have null values on table joins

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I am working on a view (not originally created by myself) and what I am trying to do is return requests (table alias req) that dont have hours allocated to them (table alias te) and i am kinda struggling to get any kind of outer join to return this on the following sql:

```
SELECT 
te.tc_date_yyyy_ww, 
te.tc_date_yyyy_mm, 
te.tc_date_yyyy, 
te.dc_date,
te.nc_request_id_fk, 
te.nc_subrequest_id_fk, 
te.tc_clock,
te.nc_hours, 
te.nc_amount, 
te.nc_discipline_id_fk,
te.tc_discipline_desc, 
req.tc_request_name, 
req.mc_project_cost,
req.nt_fetr_project, 
req.nc_bus_unit_id_fk, 
req.nc_location_id_fk,
req.nc_cemt_status_id_fk,
coord.tc_user_fname || ' ' || coord.tc_user_lname AS projectcoodname,
assoc.tc_fname || ' ' || assoc.tc_lname AS empname,
assoc_disc.tc_long_desc AS user_discipline,
sr.tc_name AS child_project, 
sr.tc_cost_center_or_wbs,
sr.tc_cost_center_nbr, 
sr.tc_cost_center_desc,
sr.tc_profit_center_desc, 
sr.tc_profit_center_nbr, 
sr.tc_wbs_nbr,
sr.tc_wbs_desc, 
sr.nc_child_type_id_fk, 
sre.nc_estimate,
stat_li.tc_med_desc AS req_status,
NVL(PP.NC_PRIORITY,0) AS PRIORITY
 FROM te07fear.tbye10_time_entry te,
      te07fear.tbxg100_requests req,
      (SELECT *
         FROM te07fear.tbye05_form_users
        WHERE tc_role_id_fk = 'project_coordinator') coord,
      te07fear.tbye07_subrequest sr,
      te07fear.tbye08_subrequest_est sre,
      te07fear.tbye02_list_items stat_li,
      te07fear.tbye04_associates assoc,
      te07fear.tbxg95_dropdowns assoc_disc,
      TE07FEAR.TBYF43_PROJECT_PRIORITY PP
WHERE 
    te.tc_clock = assoc.tc_clock
  AND 
    te.nc_subrequest_id_fk = sr.nc_subrequest_id(+)
  AND 
    te.nc_subrequest_id_fk = sre.nc_subrequest_id_fk(+)
  AND 
    te.tc_clock = sre.tc_clock(+)
  AND 
    te.nc_request_id_fk = req.nc_request_id
  AND 
    te.nc_request_id_fk = coord.nc_form_id_fk
  AND 
    assoc.nc_discipline_id_fk = assoc_disc.nc_key_id
  AND 
    req.nc_cemt_status_id_fk = stat_li.nc_value_id
  AND
    TE.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK = PP.NC_REQUEST_ID_FK
  AND
    TE.NC_SUBREQUEST_ID_FK = PP.NC_SUB_REQUEST_ID_FK
  AND
    TE.TC_DATE_YYYY_WW = PP.TC_DATE_YYYY_WW
  AND
    TE.TC_CLOCK = PP.TC_CLOCK_NUMBER
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.I am assuming that a left outer join should enable me to to this.

Thanks
JC

Comment: Jeepers, I would love to help you but without any kinds of table ddl, sample data, and expected results, my answer would be as good as shooting fish in a barrel. Take your time and break down this problem into a smaller sample data set and post it here, I bet you will get an answer within minutes. ;-)

Comment: Too bad you seem stuck with old Oracle notation for joins. If you need to do an outer join on table `te`, you need the `(+)` notation on ALL conditions in the `where` clause where you have a column from `te` on the other side, and **also** possibly on further join conditions. For example: if you need an outer join on table `a` out of tables `a, b, c`, you may need things like `where a.id = b.id(+) and b.other_id = c.other_id(+)`. It would be much better if you were allowed to rewrite using standard ANSI join syntax.

Comment: @mathguy  - Appeciate the inormation

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you actually need `NOT EXISTS` clause, not outer join.
Here's a simplified snippet, to show you what I mean (skipped most of the query, but you'l get the idea):

```
SELECT req.tc_request_name, 
       req.mc_project_cost,
       req.nt_fetr_project, 
       req.nc_bus_unit_id_fk, 
       req.nc_location_id_fk,
       req.nc_cemt_status_id_fk
  FROM te07fear.tbxg100_requests req
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1
                     from te07fear.tbye10_time_entry te
                    where te.nc_request_id_fk = req.nc_request_id)
;
```

Let me know if that's the case and if it serves the purpose.

Cheers